# Why is mysql slow at performing UPDATE WHERE IN query (on the PK) as I iterate deeper into the table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two databases:

### Database A

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
`job_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`in_b`, tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`),
 KEY `idx_inb` (`in_b`),
)
```

### Database B

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs_copy` (
`job_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`)
)
```

### Performance Issue

I am performing a query where I get a batch of jobs (100 jobs) from Database A and create a copy in Database B, then mark them as `in_b` with a:

```
UPDATE jobs SET in_b=1 WHERE job_id IN (1,2,3.....)
```

This worked fine. The rows were being transferred fairly quickly until I reached job_id values > 2,000,000. The select query to get a batch of jobs was still quick (4ms), but the update statement was much slower.

Is there a reason for this? I searched MySQL Docs / Stackoverflow to see if converting the "IN" to a "OR" query would improve this query, but the general consensus was that a "ON" query will be faster in most cases.

If anyone has any insight as to why this is happening and how I can avoid this slowdown as I reach 10mil + rows, I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks in advance,

Ash

P.S. I am completing these update/select/insert through two RESTful services (one attached to each DB) but this is a constant from job_id 1 to through 2mil etc.

Comment: So you're updating 2M rows and are surprised it's not instant? PS: your schemas refer to a non-existing column

Comment: Sorry. I am updating 100 rows at a time.

Restful-B: GET 100 rows from A
DB-B: INSERT those 100 rows
Restful-B: POST recieved those 100 rows from A
DB-A: UPDATE 100 rows

repeat

Comment: Can you use `WHERE job_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100` rather than `IN (1,2,3)` ? Are databases A and B on the same server, or different servers? Do you have the flexibility to add some indexes?

Comment: @OllieJones - Databases are on different servers, I can add indexes. I can't guarantee a BETWEEN query will work because the Restful-B service only tells Restful-A to update jobs that were successfully copied. 

i.e. If of the 100 rows recieved (from A), only 98 were successfully copied (into B), then the update will only be done on those 98 jobs.

Comment: `job_id` is not your primary key, try to search with primary key or at least add an index on your `job_id`. By the way, if you just want to copy(synchronise) your database, why don't you use database replication? Here is something about [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` query is progressively slowing down because it's having to read many rows from your large table to find the rows it needs to process. It's probably doing a so-called *full table scan* because there is no suitable index.

Pro tip: when a query starts out running fast, but then gets slower and slower over time, it's a sign that optimization (possibly indexing) is required.

To optimize this query:

```
UPDATE jobs SET in_b=1 WHERE job_id IN (1,2,3.....)
```

Create an index on the job_id column, as follows.

```
CREATE INDEX job_id_index ON jobs(job_id)
```

This should allow your query to locate the records which it needs to update very quickly with its `IN (2,3,6)` search filter.